# Convergence of difference quotient in $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $f \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, where $p \in (1,\infty)$. Let us define $f^{i}_{h}$ as

$$
f^{i}_{h}(x) := \frac{f(x+he_{i}) - f(x)}{|h|}.
$$

Prove that

$$
||f^{i}_{h} - D_{i}f||_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} \to 0.
$$

I don't have any idea how to prove that. I've just heard about 7.11 from Trudinger's book about elliptic equations, but I don't have any concludes from that lemmas. Maybe it's a simple fact, but I will be really grateful for help, proof or source, where can I find that.

Comment: I see two possible ways to try to prove this: 1) Test $f_h^i-D_if$ against a smooth, compactly supported function. Using the definition of $D_if$ and a change of variables, you get that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f_h^i-D_if)\varphi dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(\varphi_h^i - D_i\varphi) dx$$ and then go from there (by Hölder inequality or something like that). 2) By Meyer-Serrin we can approximate $f$ by smooth functions, use that to get to the result.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Both of your tips are interesting. I focused on the first one. I forgot that we can change variables and obtain something like integrating by parts for difference quotient. It really helps me with my problem :)